# Fluid mechanics - Question Poiseuille exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow

A little help/direction would be very helpful:

> The needle of a syringe has a diameter $d=0.6mm$ and its length is
> $l=2cm$. The water flow forced in the needle is $Q=10^{-7} m^3 s^{-1}$

Assuming laminar flow, calculate:

1. The average speed of water
2. What is the pressure drop necessary to have such a flow
   I think I'm OK with the 1:
   $Q=S×V$ so:

$$V=Q/S=10^{-7}/( 6×10^{-3} × 6 ×10^{-3}) = 8.84×10^{-4} m s^{-1}$$

2/ For this one I assume I have to use Poiseuille equation:

$$\Delta P = \frac{8\mu LQ}{\pi R^4}$$

but I don't know how to do as I don't have the dynamic viscosity of the water ($\mu$). I don't know if I suppose to know this value (as it depend on temperature I presume?) or if I have to / can express the pressure drop without knowing this value.

Can someone help me/push me a little in the right direction?

Comment: I understand you're not a native English speaker but understand that the word **I** is ALWAYS capitalised, regardless of its position in a sentence.

Comment: Don't forget the $\pi$ for the cross-sectional area $S$, since capillaries are usually assumed to be circular. Also, you need to halve the diameter to get the radius.

Answer (score 2):

Less than 5 seconds of googling and I found the [dynamic viscosity](https://www.engineersedge.com/physics/water__density_viscosity_specific_weight_13146.htm#:%7E:text=The%20dynamic%20viscosity%20of%20water,centipoise%20at%2020%20%C2%B0C.) of water:

$$\mu=8.90\times 10^{-4}\text{ }\mathrm{Pa.s}$$

at $25^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ of temperature.

A table of dynamic viscosity dependence on temperature is also provided in that link.

> or if I have to / can express the pressure drop without knowing this
> value.

No, of course you can't calculate $\Delta P$ without knowing $\mu$.

Comment: People doing fluid dynamics courses should know the viscosity of water at room temperature from the top of their head. At 20 degrees it is 0.001 Pa s.

Comment: @Bernhard That's silly. I've done a lot of FD in my time and still don't know that value 'of the top of my head'.

Comment: I've known it in my head since 1962 when I had my first course in fluid dynamics:  1 centipoise = 0.01 Poise

Comment: Sure Chet but 'Daphoque' isn't a habitual user of FD, methinks.

Comment: thanks, finally get an answer from our professor indicating we have to use 1x10^-3

Answer (score 1):

I don't confirm your velocity calculation.  The cross sectional area of the capillary is $$\frac{\pi D^2}{4}=2.83\times 10^{-7}\ m^2$$So the velocity is 0.354 m/s.

Comment: haha yeah thanks stupid mistake !